# where to place the php code with html tags when populating data into combobox from db? (mySQL with phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi I'm very new to php and I'm trying to load combo boxes with data in a particular field in the database. I'm using phpMyAdmin. It gives the error as Connection failed. I'm not sure about where to place the php code properly with the html tags. This is the code.

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "Zoo";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
       {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       } 

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT quizName FROM quiz");   
    echo "<select id='category' class='form-control input-default' name='category'  
    id='category' style='width:300px;'>"
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo " <option value = '".$row[quiz]."'>".$row[quiz]."</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a database client *application* that is written in PHP. You don't use it with your own PHP code.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: This isn't phpmyadmin, it's just php. phpmyadmin is a third-party web page that you can use to access a MySQL database.

Comment: How are you saving this PHP? Have you placed it in a file, with a `.php` extension, in your Apache web root?

Comment: No I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this php codes

```
   <?php

    $servername = "localhost";

    $username = "root";

    $password = "";

    $dbname = "Zoo";

$connect=mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed"); 

    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Connection failed"); 


    $result=mysql_query("SELECT quizName FROM quiz");  

    ?>


    <select>

    <?php

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

        {
?>
<option value = "<?php echo $row['quizName'] ?>"><?php echo $row['quizName'] ?></option>

            <?php

        }

        ?>

            </select>


            <?php

    mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

with SQL Codes

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.7.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 27, 2014 at 01:17 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.20
-- PHP Version: 5.5.15

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `zoo`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `quiz`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quiz` (
`quizID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quizName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `quizDescription` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `quiz`
--

INSERT INTO `quiz` (`quizID`, `quizName`, `quizDescription`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', 'abc description'),
(2, 'xyz', 'xyz description');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `quiz`
--
ALTER TABLE `quiz`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`quizID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `quiz`
--
ALTER TABLE `quiz`
MODIFY `quizID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Hi this didn't give errors but it didn't populate the combo box.

Comment: can you please share the structure of your QUIZ table.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11grtih&s=8

Comment: I have tried the same PHP code with the table similar to the link you have provided and found it is working.Also please try sql codes from my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this line you reference a field quiz:

```
echo " <option value = '".$row[quiz]."'>".$row[quiz]."</option>";
```

But you select quizName previously.

So if this is the only error you should replace the above line with this:

```
echo " <option value = '".$row['quizname']."'>".$row['quizname']."</option>";
```

(And you should enclose between apostrophes the field name string constant.)

And verifying your code's output in a browser can help much in debugging it.

Comment: no it doesn't work,, http://oi57.tinypic.com/3165fsi.jpg This is the error I get

Comment: Hmm. It seems you entered this php somewhere into phpmyadmin... Phpmyadmin is for administrating your mysql databases, not for programming in php. It is something completely different. You should create a new file on your webserver with the above content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "local host";
```

You can't have a space in a hostname. You probably mean `"localhost"`